# Pandas finding max value in rolling window of time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table `df` with columns `"timestamp"` and `"Y"`. I want to add another column `"MaxY"` which contains the largest `Y` value at most 24 hours in the future. That is

```
df.MaxY.iloc[i] = df[(df.timestamp > df.timestamp.iloc[i]) &
                     (df.timestamp < df.timestamp.iloc[i] + timedelta(hours=24))].Y.max()
```

Obviously, computing it like that is very slow. Is there a better way?

In a similar case of computing `"SumY"` I can do it using a trick with `cumsum()`. However here similar tricks don't seem to work.

As requested, an example table (MaxY is the output. Input is the first two columns only).

```
-------------------------------
| timestamp        | Y | MaxY |
-------------------------------
| 2016-03-29 12:00 | 1 |   3  |  rows 2 and 3 fall within 24 hours, so MaxY = max(2,3)
| 2016-03-29 13:00 | 2 |   4  |  rows 3 and 4 fall in the time interval, so MaxY = max(3, 4)
| 2016-03-30 11:00 | 3 |   4  |  rows 4, 5, 6 all fall in the interval so MaxY = max(4, 3, 2)
| 2016-03-30 12:30 | 4 |   3  |  max (3, 2)
| 2016-03-30 13:30 | 3 |   2  |  row 6 is the only row in the interval
| 2016-03-30 14:00 | 2 | nan? |  there are no rows in the time interval. Any value will do.
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Help us to help you! Please provide a sample data set with 5-7 rows and expected output/result set based on the provided sample.

Comment: @JohnE, as I understand, `rolling()` is only for windows of fixed number of rows. Mine are for a fixed time interval.

Comment: @MaxU, I was hoping a snippet of naive code would be good enough.  Now I've added a table too. Is it clearer?

Comment: @JohnE, i tried to do it using `rolling` and `resample` as well, but i couldn't do it properly. Could you please show us the way? Thanks!

Comment: @MaxU  OK, just for you I gave it a shot.  ;-)  It was trickier than I thought but I think is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's wrong with

```py
df['MaxY'] = df[::-1].Y.shift(-1).rolling('24H').max()
```

`df[::-1]` reverses the df (you want it "backwards") and `shift(-1)` takes care of the "in the future".

Comment: `shift(-1)` is wrong, `df[::-1].Y.rolling('24H', closed='left').max()` is the right way to exclude current row. But thanks for pointing out that rolling works with time intervals. Maybe it didn't use to?

Comment: `shift` was the way to go back in 2020, `pandas` is not too keen in backwards compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with resample/rolling.  I get a weird warning using pandas version 0.18.0 and python 3.5.  I don't think it's a concern but not sure why it is generated.

This assumes index is 'timestamp', if not, precede the following with `df = df.set_index('timestamp')`:

```
>>> df2 = df.resample('30min').sort_index(ascending=False).fillna(np.nan)
>>> df2 = df2.rolling(48,min_periods=1).max()
>>> df.join(df2,rsuffix='2')

                     Y   Y2
timestamp                  
2016-03-29 12:00:00  1  3.0
2016-03-29 13:00:00  2  4.0
2016-03-30 11:00:00  3  4.0
2016-03-30 12:30:00  4  4.0
2016-03-30 13:30:00  3  3.0
2016-03-30 14:00:00  2  2.0
```

On this tiny dataframe it seems to be about twice as fast, but you'd have to test it on a larger dataframe to get a reasonable idea of relative speed.

Hopefully this is somewhat self expanatory.  The ascending sort is necessary because rolling only allows a backwards or centered window as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you and ++! I was always playing with '1H' frequency and always had bad results - why did it do the trick using '30min' frequency???

Comment: @MaxU  there are some times like 12:30 and 13:30 in the data so might not come out exactly the same with 1hr?

Comment: I see it now, thank you for the solution and explanation!

Comment: Well, that's not very good on real data. The argument to `resample()` will either be small and thus blow up the table (especially if there are any time gaps in it) or it will be large and thus produce wrong numbers (maybe I can live with that).

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė  Did you actually try it?  I will be surprised if it is not faster on real data because your way is doing basically 2*n^2 inequality tests which are slower and slower as data gets bigger.  It is a fair point you make with resample and how fine your data is, but I'm not sure if much can be done about that -- though you can make resample pretty fine if it turns out to be fast enough.

Comment: I'd try the proposed way first, but you might then look here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#sparse-resampling  if that is not a sufficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an `apply()` solution that may run faster. Function returns the max of a time-conditional series from each row.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

def daymax(row):         
    ser = df.Y[(df.timestamp > row) &
               (df.timestamp <= row + timedelta(hours=24))]
    return ser.max()

df['MaxY'] = df.timestamp.apply(daymax)

print(df)

#            timestamp  Y  MaxY
#0 2016-03-29 12:00:00  1   3.0
#1 2016-03-29 13:00:00  2   4.0
#2 2016-03-30 11:00:00  3   4.0
#3 2016-03-30 12:30:00  4   3.0
#4 2016-03-30 13:30:00  3   2.0
#5 2016-03-30 14:00:00  2   NaN
```